# How can I correct MySQL Load Error

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load, local

I'm not quite sure a similar question to this was closed by I'm trying to execute the following MySQL program.

```
mysql -e "load data local infile \
'/tmp/ept_inventory_wasp_export_04292013.csv' into \
table wasp_ept_inv fields terminated by ',' \
lines terminated by '\n' ;"
```

at the bash command line and get this error

`ERROR 1148 (42000) at line 1: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

How can I work around this problem?

I am actually running this command from a Python program, but pulled the command out to try fiddling with it at the bash command line.

I've seen how I can modify my.cnf (local-infile), but I do not want that global a change if I can avoid it.

Here's the MySQL version.

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As documented under [Security Issues with `LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data-local.html):

> To deal with these problems, we changed how [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) is handled as of MySQL 3.23.49 and MySQL 4.0.2 (4.0.13 on Windows):
>
> - By default, all MySQL clients and libraries in binary distributions are compiled with the `--enable-local-infile` option, to be compatible with MySQL 3.23.48 and before.
> - If you build MySQL from source but do not invoke configure with the `--enable-local-infile` option, [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) cannot be used by any client unless it is written explicitly to invoke [`mysql_options(... MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, 0)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-options.html). See [Section 20.6.6.49, “`mysql_options()`”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-options.html).
> - You can disable all [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) statements from the server side by starting [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html) with the [`--local-infile=0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) option.
> - For the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) command-line client, enable `LOAD DATA LOCAL` by specifying the [`--local-infile[=1]`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile) option, or disable it with the [`--local-infile=0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile) option. For [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html), local data file loading is off by default; enable it with the [`--local`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_local) or `-L` option. In any case, successful use of a local load operation requires that the server permits it.
> - If you use [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) in Perl scripts or other programs that read the `[client]` group from option files, you can add the `local-infile=1` option to that group. However, to keep this from causing problems for programs that do not understand `local-infile`, specify it using the `loose-` prefix:
>
>   ```
>   [client]
>   loose-local-infile=1
>   ```
> - If [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:
>
>   > `ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Comment: That's not helping me at all. I want a workaround. And I put local-infile in my.cnf, and that did not change the error. I start MySQL with the statements provided when installed. I don't do anything special. Your answer still does not provide a workaround, because I have not specifically disabled anything.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus if it's not helping you at all, why did you accept the answer then?? Why didn't you accept your own answer instead???

Answer (score 48):

The workaround for this is to modify the command line `mysql -e` to pass in the `--local-infile=1` argument like this:

```
mysql --local-infile=1 -u username -p `
```

Then run the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command again.

Comment: this however works: `mysql  -u username -p --local-infile db -A`

Answer (score 10):

`local-infile` needs to enabled on both the server and the client.  You can accomplish this by adding `local-infile = 1` to the appropriate section in each end's `my.cnf` (Unix) or `my.ini` (Windows) file.  For example, on the client:

```
[client]
local-infile = 1
```

You can also enable this at runtime on the server by setting the system variable `local_infile`:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
```

However, you still need to enable it on the client.  You can do this at runtime by adding a command-line parameter to the `mysql` command:

```
mysql --local-infile=1 ...
```

If you're using Amazon Web Services RDS, you can configure the server setting by editing or creating a Parameter Group.  Look for the `local_infile` parameter.  You may need to restart your server after applying the changes.

Comment: `SET local_infile=1;` will fail on newer MySQL versions.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;` is what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your MySQL server does not have `LOAD DATA LOCAL` enabled.  See this section of MySQL documentation:

> If LOAD DATA LOCAL is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:
>
> ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Here is link to the page I got this from:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data-local.html