# load data local infile mysql server php Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, load-data-infile

I am posting the resolution since it drove me crazy for a few days -- it turned out to be the AppArmor settings. This thread finally got me solved:
[How can I get around MySQL Errcode 13 with SELECT INTO OUTFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile)

I see this is marked as duplicate but all the other suggestions seem to point to editing my.cnf which is not working for me.

I cannot get Load Data Local Infile to work. My MySQL server version is 5.5.41 and my Ubuntu version is 14.04.2. My my.cnf has "local-infile" under mysql, mysqld and client. I am below specifying flag 128 in the connection string per another post on Stackoverflow. The code below works great when I run it on the client but now that it lives on the server it continuously throws

> "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.

EDIT, running this from command line is successful:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/aa/ER.csv'
    ->      INTO TABLE ER_import
    ->      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ->      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    ->      IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->     (Paid_Amount,
    -> Pro_Number,
    -> Invoice,
    -> Ship_Date,
    -> BL,
    -> Carrier_Name,
    -> Check_Number,
    -> Paid_Date,
    -> Shipper_City,
    -> Shipper_State,
    -> Shipper_Name_1,
    -> Recipient_City,
    -> Recipient_State,
    -> Recipient_Name_1,
    -> Batch_Number,
    -> Actual_Weight,
    -> Billed_Amount
    -> );
Query OK, 8585 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.21 sec)
Records: 8585  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4
```

yet this keeps retuning that the file is not found: "File '/home/aa/ER.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)" the file is definitely there and permission are correct:

```
$delete = "DELETE FROM ER_import";

 if (!mysqli_query($conn,$delete))
   {
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
   }

$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/aa/ER.csv'
     INTO TABLE ER_import
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (Paid_Amount,
Pro_Number,
Invoice,
Ship_Date,
BL,
Carrier_Name,
Check_Number,
Paid_Date,
Shipper_City,
Shipper_State,
Shipper_Name_1,
Recipient_City,
Recipient_State,
Recipient_Name_1,
Batch_Number,
Actual_Weight,
Billed_Amount
);
eof;


if($results = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
  echo $file. " has been imported!";
} else die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Is it something obvious??

Comment: See also [How can I correct MySQL Load Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16285864).

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE DIR_FILE
     INTO TABLE ER_import
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
eof;

$query = str_replace('DIR_FILE',$dir.$file,$query);
```

because `<<<eof` means you don't want php to parse anything inside your following string. But you are trying to `$dir$file` that means you are expecting thta php will replace this vars with values.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nonintuitive twist to the meaning of `LOCAL` in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.  You only need to use `LOCAL` when the file you're loading is *not* local to the server. `LOCAL` tells the MySQL client to pick up a local file and place it in a temporary directory on the server.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Try taking the word `LOCAL` out of your command when you run that php script on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few years back.

local-infile needs to enabled for both the client and server.

I would recommend that you try running `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from the command line interface first before trying in PHP. To make sure that the connection from the client enables local-infile, run this command:

`mysql --local-infile=1 -h REPLACE_HOST_IP -u username -p`

Good luck!

Comment: interesting, i got this error: Host ' hostname ' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: Well, let's fix that first. We need to make sure that the server accepts remote mysql connection. For that, modify your my.cnf file accordingly.  Also grant access the user `username` to connect remotely as such:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'`

Comment: i got past that -- do you see anything in my edits that are obvious?