# MySQL Loading Data Error

Tags: mysql

```
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE "file.txt"
REPLACE INTO TABLE file
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(attribute1, attribute2)
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE "file2.txt"
REPLACE INTO TABLE file2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(attribute3, attribute4)
```

I have a single text file composed of several of these "LOAD DATA" commands.  I receive an error message saying line 6, or the start of the 2nd command, is not proper syntax.  And if I try to introduce a "lines terminated by '\n'" code, it says it is not allowed with my mysql version.

Comment: Perhaps you need to terminate the individual `LOAD DATA` statements?

Comment: Yes, you should add a ';' at the end of each load statement. And what version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: The ';' helped remove the 2nd error message, but now it points to line 1 and says "the used command is not allowed with this mysql version".

Comment: What is the version there?

Comment: try add local-infile=1 into your [mysqld], see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/enable-load-data-local-infile

Comment: it says the version is 5.1

Comment: the addition of --local-infile worked.  Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a ';' at the end of each load statement.

```
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE "file.txt"
REPLACE INTO TABLE file
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(attribute1, attribute2);


LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE "file2.txt"
REPLACE INTO TABLE file2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(attribute3, attribute4);
```

See also  [ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version)

You can specify that as an additional option when setting up your client connection:

```
mysql -u myuser -p --local-infile somedatabase
```