# How to load file in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to execute this MySQL program using a shell script

```
load data local infile 'MRCOLS.RRF' into table MRCOLS fields 
terminated by '|' ESCAPED BY '' lines terminated by '\r\n'
(@col,@des,@ref,@min,@av,@max,@fil,@dty)
SET COL = NULLIF(@col,''),
DES = NULLIF(@des,''),
REF = NULLIF(@ref,''),
MIN = NULLIF(@min,''),
AV = NULLIF(@av,''),
MAX = NULLIF(@max,''),
FIL = NULLIF(@fil,''),
DTY = NULLIF(@dty,'');`
```

and I am getting `ERROR 1148 (42000) at line 25: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

I have cross checked the command with syntax of MySQL, but nothing helped me.

MySQL Version :
`mysql 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the feature you use open a security hole.So if you want to use it you would need to enable the settings manually.

```
mysql -u myuser -p --local-infile thedb
```

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version)

Comment: Thank you so much.. I had been working for one day on this. You saved my time. Moreover, this is my first ever question in stack overflow :P