# how to overcome the following issue using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Hello I am using the following version of MySQL:

```
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.7.18 Homebrew
```

I am trying to use the following command to load a csv as follows:

```
   mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/adolf/Downloads/DB2.csv' INTO TABLE info;
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
    ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

So I really would appreciate support to overcome that issue,

Comment: mysql -u myuser -p --local-infile somedatabase 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update your SQL version to 6.2.5. I am reading reports that this error was solved by an update. There was a secruity hole which was patched but then fixed properly in the later version. I hope this helps

Comment: Hello I really appreciate the support, could you please tell me how to upgrade my version ?