# How to solve Error 1148 from MySql workbench and not cmd?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am running the following statement to import data:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE     'C:\\Users\\talkohavy\\Desktop\\MySQL_data\\categories.csv'
INTO TABLE BI_EX_OLTP.categories 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

And then I get this error:

> error code 1148. the used command is not allowed with this mysql version.

How can I enable loading local data using the **MySql Workbench** and not the **cmd**?

Comment: There's [two answers here apart from `--local-infile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18437689/243245): my.cnf or SET GLOBAL. Do either of those work for you?

Comment: I ran the line: SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
Its status became on.
but still when i tried the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE..." i got the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the new versions of Workbench (having the same issue in Workbench 8.0.12). I did not have this issue in the 5.7.x version of Workbench, and downgrading to this version has fixed the issue for me.

This bug is documented here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891

I recommend either downgrading to an older version of Workbench, or using a different means to execute the command (such as through the mysql CLI command, or using another tool to connect such as DataGrip, etc).

Answer (score 9):

This solution works for version 8.0.18:

In the `advanced` tab of the connection, put `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` in the `others` box.

[image: setting_MySQL_workbench]

Comment: This worked for me. Wish we could change approved answer per current versions.

Comment: this was by far the best option that I saw! worked for me!