# Step through CSV file incrementally in Python

Tags: python, mysql, executemany

I am trying to speed up loading a large CSV file into a MySQL database. Using this code it takes about 4 hours to load a 4GB file:

```
with open(source) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    insert_sql = """ INSERT INTO billing_info_test (InvoiceId, PayerAccountId, LinkedAccountId) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) """
    for row in csv_reader:
        cursor.execute(insert_sql,row)
        print(cursor.rowcount, 'inserted with LinkedAccountId', row[2], 'at', datetime.now().isoformat())
    print("Committing the DB")
    mydb.commit(
cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

I want to use the [executemany()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) statement to make this faster. For that, you have to pass a list of tuples to the second argument.

If I build the list on each row iteration it gets too large, and I get out of memory errors when the list gets too large, and the script crashes.

I am not able to get a length of csv_reader or csv_file to use in a range statement.

How can I loop through the CSV file 1000 rows at a time and store the result in a list, use it in executemany, then store the next 1000 rows, etc until the end of the CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

If you need high speed inserts in mysql, you can try to use:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/my_file.csv' INTO TABLE my_table;`

Comment: Not having any luck there either. I tried putting local-infile=1 in my.ini. Then I restarted the service. Now I'm getting this error: `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version` I tried putting it under [mysql] and the [mysqld] section and restarting the service each time.

Comment: I think this post should help you a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version

Comment: Thanks! That did help. I am loading the file now. However, I do still have to learn how to handle this programmatically. Hope I can figure it out!

Comment: That was SUPER fast! I was done in about 10 minutes. However all the rows are NULL when I do a select. So that didn't quite work. :/

Comment: yep. its supposed to be this fast. try to check if all of your columns(mysql) match the columns of your .csv file.

Comment: Ok, no they don't after the import. ALLof the fields are NULL. But when I load the data with the code snippet I posted in the OP, all of the columns are populated correctly.

Comment: For example if I examine the records in the database after loading the file directly into MySQL all the entries in the table look like this: https://pastebin.com/SiyPs8Yn

Comment: I'm trying again with this info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile

Comment: No luck that time either. MySQL reported success importing the file. However when I do selects from the table there is no data present: https://pastebin.com/7jLtx1kH

Comment: You can try to read the csv columns, one by one to check if the values are ok. Did you try to load by column? `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE csv_file  INTO TABLE my_table COLUMNS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\\r\\n" (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

A small hint:

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: rows = iter(range(10))

In [3]: while True:
   ...:     batch = [*itertools.islice(rows, 3)]
   ...:     if not batch:
   ...:         break
   ...:     print(batch)
   ...:
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]
```

But I should agree with `@heliosk` that a better solution is to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` for large files. You may also need to [disable keys](https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts) until the import is finished.