# What is wrong in the command?

Tags: mysql

**ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.** 
The above error appears when the load data query execute.
I was unable to detect what is wrong in the query. 
Please help. Thanks.

Create table SQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    field1  char(8) NOT NULL,
    field2  varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    field3  varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    field4  varchar(100),
    field5  text,
    field6  char(8),
    field7  char(1)
) CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4;
```

Load table sql

```
load data local infile 'E:/insert/table1.RRF' into table table1 fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\r\n'
(@field1,@field2,@field2,@field4,@field5,@field6,@field7)
SET field1 = @field1,
field2 = @field2,
field2 = @field2,
field4 = NULLIF(@field4,''),
field5 = NULLIF(@field5,''),
field6 = NULLIF(@field6,''),
field7 = NULLIF(@field7,'');
```

Edit 1:
Variable of  local_infile in MySQL is set to ON

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.

In general this means that `secure_file_priv` server setting is disabled (set to NULL) or set to some definite directory (not empty string).

If it is disabled then `LOAD DATA INFILE` is not available until this setting enabling (which needs server restart).

If it is set to some directory then loaded file must be posessed in this directory strongly.

> `load data local infile 'E:/insert/table1.RRF'`

If `E:` is local device/volume then `LOCAL` makes no sense.

`LOCAL` keyword means "copy remote file to local temporary folder before loading" - so it makes sense only for remote files.

It is applicable only if `secure_file_priv` is enabled and set to empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!
Adding 
`[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
`
in to my.ini will set the secure_file_priv to disable and the load data works. 
Also, remove local from the queries.