# Cannot load local infile to mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, mysql-workbench, cleardb

When trying to upload a local file into an existing table using mysql workbench (that is hosted through keroku clearDB), I am receiving the following error:

"Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

```html
load data local infile '/Users/xxx/mydatasheet.csv'
into table `my-table`
fields terminated by ','
ignore 1 rows;
```

I believe this is due to my local infile value being set to OFF.

When uploading files to the database hosted on my local server everything works fine, no errors.

My file has approx 36 columns and 55,000 rows, attempting to load through the the table data import wizard is not working due to size.

I have tried the following without any luck - I continue to get the same error.

**Added all variations to my.cnf file under [mysql] and [client]**

local_infile=ON

local_infile=“ON”

local_infile=1

local_infile=“1”

**Tried adding**

OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 under mysl workbench connections (under advanced tab in the “Other” section)

**Tried the following sql queries**

set global local_infile="ON";

set global local_infile=1;

But I do not have super privileges.

I am unsure of how to proceed, hoping for some other suggestions so I can successfully upload a local file into my sql table.

Thank you

Comment: In the advanced tab of the connection, put OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 in the others box.

Comment: @svikramjeet tried that as well, still receiving the same error.

Comment: Please check if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version