# Error Code: 13. Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/f2s/home amardata.csv' (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '\home\ram\ardata.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE archive FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',
'ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '' IGNORE 1 LINES
(content_id,@title,summary,archive_url,size,created_date,length,encoding,image_preview,
live_status,platform,m_content_id,live_url,uv_album_id,uv_cat_id,istrending,isfeatured,
isSacinApproved,sachin_user,isrecent,youtubebroadcasterid,youtubestreamid,youtubeurl) 
SET title=CONCAT('nagar:',@title);
```

i am using `mysql 5.5.37-0` with `ubuntu0.12.04.1` and i want run this query on `MySQL` workbench. but error is Error Code: 13. Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/f2s/home amardata.csv' (Errcode: 2)

Comment: I think you have to use a slash as seperator in your path.

Comment: There are beckslasches in yout path ´'\home\ram\ardata.csv'` think it must be `'/home/ram/ardata.csv'`

Comment: @Jens I have used but  error obtain this  :- Error Code: 29. File '/home/ram/ardata.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)

Comment: Where is the file `ardata.csv` located? is it in the specified directory and is it accessible?

Comment: I get location using command ctrl+l   and  directory is accessible.

Comment: Can youu try to copy the file to `/tmp` and import it from there?

Comment: @Jens   still not work this query......................

Comment: possible duplicate of [LOAD DATA INFILE Error Code : 13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13)