# How to import comma separated values from a file into mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to import data from a file into the mysql through command line only. I am using the following command but getting the following error.

Mysql>load data infile '/root/data.txt' into table test.emp fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/root/data.txt' (Errcode: 13)

Table structure is:

Emp_ID      int

Emp_name        varchar

Emp_city      varchar

Content of data.txt

1,abc,London

2,def,Alberta

3,hjk,Toronto

Could somebody will help me on this how to do this via command line or any other way out?

Comment: check access permission of '/root/data.txt'

Comment: 777 is the permission

Comment: Do you have a phpmyadmin available? If so, it will provide you with a GUI for importing the file.

Comment: no, no access to phpmyadmin..

Comment: Here is a related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13.

Comment: @GordonLinoff....i am using CentOS 6 and there is no such Apparmor
and no such file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld