# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE "not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)"

Tags: php, mysql, permission-denied, load-data-infile

Last week this was working, and today it isn't. I have not changed the php file. All I have done in the interim is run apt-get update on my Ubuntu 15.04 server.

The MySQL statement I have is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/var/www/html/uploads/TitleList.csv" INTO TABLE tblLSITitleList FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "\"" IGNORE 5 LINES;
```

This gives the following error:

> File '/var/www/html/uploads/TitleList.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

I have tried the following solution (which was how I solved this exact problem early last week:
[LOAD DATA INFILE Error Code : 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13)

I have checked the apparmor and the uploads folder is still there.

I have also tried chmodding various permissions, including 777, but nothing helps.

Any clever suggestions?

Comment: i faced a similar issue like this and nothing works then had to changed to win server

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

```
For security reasons, when reading text files located on the server, 
the files must either reside in the database directory or be 
readable by all
```

I recommend copying your .csv file to database directory, something like

```
cp TitleList.csv /var/lib/mysql/yourdbname/TitleList.csv
```

and then

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'TitleList.csv' INTO etc ...
```

Answer (score 3):

While one could copy the CSV into the mysql data directory, however this is not a good on-going solution. If you're using SQL command-line or code, include the LOCAL option into the query.

- For Example: Instead of `LOAD DATA INFILE` try `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

If you're using cPanel or phpmyadmin to import the `CSV using LOAD DATA` then be sure to Enable `Use LOCAL keyword`. This worked for me in a shared server environment.

This should prevent one having to copy the CSV to the MySQL data directory each time.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  In order to set permissions, I first executed chmod($fileName, 0777); theoretically a security risk, but I delete the file at the end of the import operation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the LOCAL keyword worked for me. I also made sure that the file has READ permission, since I'm working in Ubuntu:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/name.csv'
    INTO TABLE 'table_name'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `LOAD DATA INFILE` is a success with the first dataset.
But with the second dataset, I've got this errcode 13.

What I did (win user), I press `CTRL+ALT+DELETE` and then I selected `Start Task Manager`, then I went to the `processes` tab and selected `Excel` then pressed `End Task`.

Then tried again the `LOAD DATA INFILE` and it worked.

***Note:***  Before this, I tried to open the CSV file just to check the dataset.
It took too long, therefore, I closed it immediately before the file opened.

Maybe the incomplete process disturbed the load process.

I'm not sure with PHP because I just using phpmyadmin and play with MySQL