# Putting a file content into an sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I have a large database where customers request data that is specific to them. They usually send me the requests in a text or csv file. I was wondering if there is a way to get sql to read that file and take the content and put them into a sql query. This way I don't have to open up that file and copy and paste everything into a sql query.

Comment: not clear, what you want. what customer sending and what they want? and what you will give them?  what are they sending in format for text/csv?

Comment: What the customer is sending me are the identification number of the products that are in my database. I put those numbers into a query and get the result. I just want to know is there a way for sql to do this so I don't have to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve already answered it.

Let me add few words only.

> you can not use the csv, text,excel or anyother format directly in
>   query for DML/DDL.. you can use file directly only for export/import.

Answer (score 0):

No. MySQL is not designed to do this.

You need an intermediate script that can interpret the files and generate the queries you require.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do it: you can import the csv file to your database and then join it with any query you want.

You can load the csv file with an SQL query such as:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/test.csv"
INTO TABLE test
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

You can use other ways to import the data, see: [How to import CSV file to MySQL table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

I tried this SQL solution in Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL 5.6. For this to work you will have to put the `test.csv` file in the `/tmp` directory and do a `chmod 755 test.csv` for it to work. Otherwise MySQL is gives "Permission denied" errors. More about this issue on: [LOAD DATA INFILE Error Code : 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215231/load-data-infile-error-code-13)